# Display author name of the post with Devise gem (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, author

I create a blog with devise gem. How i can display author name of post in views. I tried something like <%= post.user %>, but it display #. How i can do it correct?

Comment: If you user model has `name` attribute then  you can do `<%= post.user.name %>`

Comment: Sure. But it first what i try to do. Display error about undifinied method 'name'.

Answer (score 0):

Devise does not provide any user metadata aside from what is necessary for the authentication system itself.  Devise will probably (depending on your configuration) give you the email address via `post.user.email`.

You need to add a first_name, last_name, or name to your user model through a new migration.